# Размер структуры в зависимости от расположения полей

Tags: c++, c, arm, struct

Добрый день, господа!

Столкнулся с проблемой выравнивания данных в структуре.
Итак, имеем 2 типа структур

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t FieldA;
    uint32_t FieldB;
    uint16_t FieldC;
    int8_t   FieldD;
} StructType1;
```

и

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t FieldA;
    uint16_t FieldC;
    uint32_t FieldB;
    int8_t   FieldD;
} StructType2;
```

Архитектура 32-битная, соответственно в памяти структуры выравниваются под 4 байта. Однако при попытке узнать размер получаем разные результаты.

```
a = (int)sizeof(StructType1);
b = (int)sizeof(StructType2);
```

> a = 12
>
> b = 16

Дело в конкретном компиляторе(IAR ARM), особенностях языка C или настройках оптимизации?

Comment: В дополнение к ответу Vlad from Moscow: можете почитать мою [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/30/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx). Там, в частности, затрагивается и этот вопрос.

Answer (score 7):

В этой структуре

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t FieldA;
    uint16_t FieldC;
    uint32_t FieldB;
    int8_t   FieldD;
}StructType2;
```

член данных `FieldB` должен быть выравнен на границу, кратную 32 битам, то есть 4 байтам. Поэтому  после поля `FieldC`  следуют дополнительные 2 байта для выравнивания следующего за ним поля.

Так как структура должна быть выравнена на границу 4 байтов, то в конец структуры добавляется еще 3 байта.

Для этой структуры

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t FieldA;
    uint32_t FieldB;
    uint16_t FieldC;
    int8_t   FieldD;
}StructType1;
```

достаточно добавить в ее конец один байт, чтобы вся структура была выравнена на границу 4 байтов.

Дело не в компиляторе, а в выравнивании структуры в соответствии с выравниванием границы для размещения ее члена данных с максимальным размером, который требует выравнивание.

Имейте в виду, что существует так называемая арифметика указателей, результат которой должен указывать на следующий член массива. Чтобы обеспечить, чтобы следующий член массива был выравнен соответствующим образом, структуры дополняются нужным количеством байтов.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так может отключать/включать выравнивание при небходимости:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct
{
  ...
} XXX;
#pragma pack(pop)
```